# GC overhead limit exceeded while reading huge txt files

Tags: java, garbage-collection, bufferedreader

I have a **20GB** folder which consist of **358** txt files and there are **733,019,372** lines total and all txt files format is below

```
77 clueweb12-0211wb-83-00000
88 clueweb12-0211wb-83-00001
82 clueweb12-0211wb-83-00002
82 clueweb12-0211wb-83-00003
64 clueweb12-0211wb-83-00004
80 clueweb12-0211wb-83-00005
83 clueweb12-0211wb-83-00006
75 clueweb12-0211wb-83-00007
```

My purpose is while program is traversing all the txt file recursively reading files line by line,seperate into two parts each line`(e.g 88 and clueweb12-0211wb-83-0003)` and put these parts into a `LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>`. Afther that, take docIds`(clueweb12-0211wb-83-00006)` from user as an argument and put the score belongs to this docIds`(83)`.If a non-existing docID is encountered, -1 should be returned as a score.For example:

```
clueweb12-0003wb-22-11553,foo,clueweb12-0109wb-78-15059,bar,clueweb12-0302wb-50-22339
```

should print out : `84,-1,19,-1,79`

And i take the path to file from user as an argument.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.*;


import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;



public class App extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>{

    public LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> list = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // Put there scores and docIds

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attr) throws IOException {

     File file =  new File(path.toString());
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     String line;

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){


        if(list.containsKey(line.split(" ")[0])){
            list.get(line.split(" ")[0]).add(line.split(" ")[1]);
        }
        else{
            list.put(line.split(" ")[0],new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")[1])));
        }

    }
        return CONTINUE;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {




        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java App spamDir docIDs ...");
            return;
        }
        Path spamDir = Paths.get(args[0]);
        String[] docIDs = args[1].split(",");

        App ap = new App();
        Files.walkFileTree(spamDir, ap);
        ArrayList scores = new ArrayList(); // keep scores in that list

        //Search the Lists in LinkedHashMap
        for(int j=0; j<docIDs.length; j++){
            Set set = ap.list.entrySet();
            Iterator i = set.iterator();
            int counter = 0;
            while(i.hasNext()){

                // if LinkedHashMap has the docID add it to scores List
                Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
                ArrayList searchList = (ArrayList) me.getValue();
                if(searchList.contains(docIDs[j])){
                    scores.add(me.getKey());
                    counter++;
                    break;


                }
                else {

                    continue;
                }

            }
            // if LinkedHashMap has not the docId add -1 to scores List
            if(counter == 0){
                scores.add("-1");
            }

        }

        String joined = String.join("," , scores);
        System.out.println(joined);

    }
}
```

But I encountered that problem :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458)
    at ceng.bim208.App.visitFile(App.java:35)
    at ceng.bim208.App.visitFile(App.java:18)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at ceng.bim208.App.main(App.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I tried to use `XmX2048M` to increase heap size but it doesn't solve my problem. What should i do?

In addition, if i run the program on a different path(include 2 txt file same format) it works correctly.

Comment: How much memory do you have on your machine? It's extremely unlikely that if the folder is 20GB on disk that it'll be able to all fit in memory... (in memory representation is almost always way more expensive than on disk format)

Comment: profile it. The previous comment is probably right but hard data never hurts.

Comment: I try to run it on VirtualBox Ubuntu and it has 4096 MB memory.

Comment: 4096 MB is 4 GB. How were you planning on fitting 20 GB of data in 4 GB of memory?

Comment: Either way, despite the naming, you are trying to shove 20gb of contents into 4gb. If your working machine has 50 gb of RAM ditch the virtual box or give it more memory

Comment: Probably you will need to paginate the map, if your files has 20G you will need more than that to store it in RAM, my recommendation is to read a piece of data, process it, then delete to read more

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an interview homework assignment. I bet that the task here is to take the mental leap and separate the data which you must hold in memory from those which you can store in an index while you parse the files.

No matter how much memory you have you'll run out of it eventually if you keep doing it like this. In your case there are some useful tips which you can use to fix this:

- Don't put everything into the memory. Build an index if you can to a separate file which only holds the necessary data
- Process the files as streams: this means that you parse the `InputStream` line by line, file by file and this way you don't have to keep them in memory.

In your case this:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> list
```

fills up the memory with the parsed `String`s. From what I understand you don't need to store the `String`s themselves but only the score. If you clarify what your task is I can help you further but currently it is not clear what your task is.

> my task is take the docIds as a command-line argument and print out their scores.

What you need is a lookup for the scores:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> docIdsWithScoresAndCounts;
```

or

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> docIdsWithScores;
```

depending on whether you want to count how many times a score appeared. The outer `Map` holds the doc ids as keys and the inner maps are lookups themselves for `score -> count`. This is a tricky variation of the counting sort algorithm: you only need to keep track of the doc ids and the scores of each doc id and since the scores are limited in size (how many digits can they have?) you end up with `O(1)` memory consumption. The rest of the data can be thrown away.

**Note that** you **only need** to store the keys of the doc ids you are interested in. You can throw away the rest.

Comment: It is a homework from school and my task is take the docIds as a command-line argument and print out their scores. If none of the 358 txt files contains docId return -1 as score.

Comment: At the begining, i thought to use second Map but since there is 733,019,372 lines docIds the map getting bigger. Since scores is limited **0 to 99** i think, i should use something like  `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

The following does it the new way and corrects some faults.

```
public Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attr)
        throws IOException {

    Files.lines(path).forEach(line -> {
        String[] keyValue = line.split(" ", 2);
        map.compute(keyValue[0],
             (key, oldList) -> {
                  List<String> list = oldList == null
                      ? new ArrayList<>()
                      : oldList;
                  list.add(keyValue[1]);
                  return list;
             }); 
    });
    return CONTINUE;
}
```

- A LinkedHashMap maintains the order of adding, which is needlessly costing memory.
- The splitting should be done once.
- The file should be closed. I use `Files.lines` which allows terse coding.
- (Tip) The Charset (encoding) is not given, hence platform default. One might consider adding it as parameter.
- The `Map.compute` comes in handy to decide on the old value (a List) whether to create a new one.

One might save on memory by not storing a `List<String>` but something like `List<byte[]>` with the bytes something like:

```
byte[] bytes = keyValue[1].getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
String s = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Compared to a String for plain ASCII you'll save half the bytes (a `char` is two bytes).

Probably a database, like an embedded java Derby or H2 will do better.

Comment: Yes lambdas are hard to read, as the syntax is so indefinite. I hope the minimalism makes an impression though. And of course telling what one still does not know is the mark of professionalism. As developer _not_ understanding something is the norm. ;)